# MYSQL Certain rows get deleted when loading data

Tags: mysql

I am new to MYSQL and I am having a problem when after I load some data into a table, certain rows get deleted. For example, lets say we have the following schema

(UserID INTEGER, UserInterests VARCHAR(200))

and I have a data like this

```
1|*|Sports
1|*|Gaming
1|*|Eat
2|*|Sports
2|*|Gaming
2|*|Sleep
```

I perform the load like this

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE Users
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|*|';
```

but then, the rows that had the same UserInterests gets deleted, so when I do the following query

```
SELECT * FROM Users;
```

I get

```
1 EAT
1 Gaming
2 Sleep
1 Sports
```

But I expected to get something like

```
1 EAT
1 Gaming
1 Sports
2 Sleep
2 Sports
2 Gaming
```

Could someone please explain where I am doing a mistake ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the expected behaviour if you would have a unique index (e.g. the primary key) for your column `UserInterests`. A unique index will prevent you from having the same data more than once. Usually, you would get a duplicate-key error, but when you use `LOCAL` in `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`, you will just get a warning, see the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html):

> LOCAL also affects error handling:
>
> - With LOAD DATA INFILE, data-interpretation and duplicate-key errors terminate the operation.
> - With LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE, data-interpretation and duplicate-key errors become warnings and the operation continues because the server has no way to stop transmission of the file in the middle of the operation. For duplicate-key errors, this is the same as if IGNORE is specified. IGNORE is explained further later in this section.

So check and correct your indexes. I assume you currently use `UserInterests` as the primary key in that table, while you probably need to have a primary key that is composed of both columns.

Comment: Thank you. It turns out I was trying to have a many-to-many relationship where I had 1 primary key and one other column. I was able to break the table down into 3 tables and fix the problem.